# Building JSON using mysql php and nested while cause Memory Allocation exhausted error

Tags: php, mysql, json, while-loop, nested-loops

I am trying to build the nested json using below code from the database values. This has already worked with smaller data, but now the same code is giving Memory issue. The error is "Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4194312 bytes)"

I tried to research and strongly feel that it is about some loop issue. can someone please help.

```
{
$conn = mysqli_connect(dbhost, dbuser, dbpass, db);
  mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
  //$Article_Info= array();
  $article_array = array();
  $seller_array = array();
  $company_id = Get_Company();
  error_log($company_id);   

               $query_article = "SELECT B.SC_PRODUCT_NAME,A.SC_CUST_PROD_CODE, A.SC_ASIN_CD,A.SC_ARTICLE_ID,A.SC_COMPANY_ID,A.SC_PROD_GIVEN_NAME,A.SC_LAST_CHECKED,A.SC_LAST_UPDATED,A.SC_DEFAULT_SELLER,A.SC_BUY_BOX_SELLER,A.SC_CURRENCY,A.SC_LAST_PRICE,A.SC_CONV_PRICE,A.SC_NET_PRICE,A.SC_CONV_NET,A.SC_PRICE_INC,A.SC_PRICE_DEC,A.SC_COUNTRY_CODE,A.SC_DOMAIN,A.SC_AVAILABLE,A.SC_AVAIL_DESCR,A.SC_PRICE_TIME,A.SC_FAULT_FLAG,A.SC_FAULT_TIME,A.SC_FAULT_MSG FROM `SC_PRICE_HIST_TBL` A INNER JOIN `SC_PRODUCT_TBL` B ON A.SC_CUST_PROD_CODE = B.SC_CUST_PROD_CODE WHERE `SC_PRICE_HIST_STATUS` = '1' AND `SC_PRICE_HIST_INSERT` = '1' AND A.SC_COMPANY_ID = '$company_id' ORDER BY B.SC_PRODUCT_NAME,`SC_ARTICLE_ID`";
               //error_log($query_article);
              $result_article = mysqli_query($conn,$query_article);

              while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_article))

              { 
                $query_seller = "SELECT `SC_SELLER_NAME`, `SC_SELLER_COUNT`, `SC_GROSS_PRICE`,`SC_NET_PRICE`, `SC_CONV_GROSS`, `SC_CONV_NET`, `SC_DELIVERY_PRICE`, `SC_CURRENCY`, `SC_LAST_UPDATED` FROM `SC_SELLER_TBL` WHERE `SC_SELLER_INSERT` = '1' AND SC_AMA_ASIN = '" .$row['SC_ASIN_CD']. "' AND SC_CUST_PROD_CODE = '" .$row['SC_CUST_PROD_CODE']. "' ORDER BY `SC_SELLER_NAME`";
                //error_log($query_seller);
                //echo $query_seller;
                $result_seller = mysqli_query($conn,$query_seller);

                while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_seller))
                {
                  $seller_arr = array ("seller_name" =>$row1['SC_SELLER_NAME'],"gross_price_seller" =>$row1['SC_GROSS_PRICE'], "net_price_seller" =>$row1['SC_NET_PRICE'], "conv_gross_price_seller" =>$row1['SC_CONV_GROSS'], "conv_net_price_seller" =>$row1['SC_CONV_NET'], "delivery_price" =>$row1['SC_DELIVERY_PRICE'], "currency" =>$row1['SC_CURRENCY'], "last_updated" =>$row1['SC_LAST_UPDATED']);
                  array_push($seller_array, $seller_arr);
                }

                $Article_Info=array("product_name" => $row['SC_PRODUCT_NAME'],"product_code"=>$row['SC_CUST_PROD_CODE'],"ASIN"=>$row['SC_ASIN_CD'],"article_id"=>$row['SC_ARTICLE_ID'],"URL"=>$row['SC_DEFAULT_SELLER'],"default_seller"=>$row['SC_DEFAULT_SELLER'], "gross_price"=>$row['SC_LAST_PRICE'], "net_price"=>$row['SC_NET_PRICE'], "conv_gross_price"=>$row['SC_CONV_PRICE'], "conv_net_price"=>$row['SC_CONV_NET'], "currency"=>$row['SC_CURRENCY'], "domain"=>$row['SC_DOMAIN'], "country"=>$row['SC_COUNTRY_CODE'], "buy_box_seller"=>$row['SC_BUY_BOX_SELLER'], "total_num_seller"=>"5", "seller_info"=>$seller_array);
                array_push($article_array, $Article_Info);
              }
              $jsonDataEncoded1 = json_encode($article_array,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE|JSON_INVALID_UTF8_IGNORE);
              echo $jsonDataEncoded1;
die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are bringing a lot of data and that is causing PHP to allocate more memory than is allocated to it.

You can increase this number by changing your php.ini configuration or use

`ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');`

as your first line in PHP

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried this and going to use it as a "last resort". I want to make the code efficient in memory management before going for short cuts.

Comment: More efficient would be to not bring all the data from the SQL server all at once.
Each query could return X records, if you have an ID column you could get from ID > 0 and ID < X
and each iteration would increase those.

Comment: I need to use the value fetched from outer recordset and then use it in where clause of inner query. so I am not sure about the range solution you are asking.

Comment: Any guidance on this ? I am stuck here. increasing memory did not solve the problem.